# Prevent globalization/localization files and folder from being published

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm currently building an ASP.NET Core hosted WebAssembly application, and when publishing there are a lot of folders created in the publish directory that correlate to all the different localizations that Blazor supports (I think). Since I don't require globalization or localization, is there a way to stop these from being created when I publish? I've read through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on the MS site, but it only seems to help with setting it up. I didn't see anything about disabling it.

I've also tried adding `<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>` to my project file with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Open your .csproj file and add **SatelliteResourceLanguages**. For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Delete your pulish folder and republish again.